# Is it possible to navigate back to the starting point when external links are clicked in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios

I've put together a very simple proof of concept app using a UIWebView (and a regular controller) to display a web page.
If the web page has external links then when clicked on the app will switch to the web app.
However there's no way to get back to my original app.

If I add a navigation controller will I get the ability to navigate back, or is there something else additionally that would be required?

(As well as launching web pages it will also be necessary to intercept custom links in the web page and perform some associated action, such as add a contact, in this situation I would also like to be able to navigate back to my app).

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your links open in Safari, the only way for your user to get back to your app is via the multitasking bar (or obviously quitting and tapping on your app icon)- there is no way to bring your app to the forefront programmatically from within another app.

I am confused though, if you have a UIWebView, the default behavior of clicking on links is to load the linked page in the same web view.

In any case, I think what you are wondering is how to intercept link clicks of a UIWebView so to do that, you should implement the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

You can then test for clicked links via testing the navigationType property for UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked

Comment: I found the problem - I was indeed using shouldStartLoadWithRequest as you guessed and was calling [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL]. I found that if the URL was of the form "www.something.com" it would launch within the UIWebView, but if it was of the form "http://www.something.com" the browser app would be launched.